# How to delete every first div when it reaches certain limit?

Tags: javascript, clone

Can anyone guide me to delete the first div, when there are 5 div's

I'm cloning a text box, users can add multiple textbox's
but when it reaches to 5, i should automatically delete the first textbox and add another at the end of the node

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

You need to count all of these divs and remove first one:

```
count = $('#container div').length;
if (count > 5) {
    $('#container div:first').remove();
}
```

To add new div:

```
$('#container').append('<div ...><textbox...></textbox></div>');
```